# Word spacing increases with long Arabic texts in WKWebView - Swift

Tags: html, wkwebview

Whenever I have something like `<p> really long Arabic text </p>` in my HTML file (loaded by WKWebView) on my app, the word spacing becomes really big and unreadable. Also, on Xcode, all the letters in the HTML file become disconnected. Is there a way to avoid this without having to break up the text into two?

If I put a span inside it like this, it fixes it:
`<p>long text part 1 <span>long text part 2</span></p>`. I can't do this because there are too many and it messes something else up.

This is how it looks like on Xcode:
[image]

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: there is no code. its just an html file loaded into a wkwebview. the issue happens whenever the text is too long and whenever that happens, xcode also splits the letters in the editor. this doesnt happen when i open the html file with safari

Answer (score 0):

You could auto break long words with inline css like so

```
<p style="overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;"> really long Arabic text </p>
```

and for the letter spacing issue you could try adding in letter-spacing: -2px; like so

```
<p style="overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; letter-spacing: -2px;"> really long Arabic text </p>
```

Adjust letter spacing number to your needs.

Comment: Neither of these fix the problem. My very long Arabic text is a very long paragraph of short Arabic words. `overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;` only breaks the words. My issue is that whenever there is a very long paragraph under a `<p>` tag, there is a very large word spacing in the `WKWebView`; it shows like 2 words per line 
 with huge gaps when it usually would show like eight words per line. The image I posted is only how it looks on Xcode. Also, `letter-spacing: -2px;` does not fix it. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try playing word-spacing like so..

```
<p style="word-spacing: -1em;"> really long Arabic text </p>
```

Might still need word breaks too..

```
<p style="overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: -1em;"> really long Arabic text </p>
```